# Using IF to apply different rounding rules based on value range - error with too many IF arguments

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I am trying to build a formula that will round a value in a cell based on these requirements

round to 0 if less than 2%
round to the nearest 2% increment up to and including 10%
round to nearest 5% increment above 10% up to and including 50%
round to nearest 10% increment above 50%

So far I have

`=IF(K98<2,"0",((IF(AND(K98>=2,K98<=10),MROUND(K98,2)))))`

This has achieved the first 2 requirements but I can't figure out how to add the remaining IF statements for the other 2.  I keep getting a too many IF arguments error

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text - [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, formatted this way to make it easier to see the logic.

```
=IF(K98<2,
  0,
  IF(AND(K98>=2,K98<=10),
     MROUND(K98,2)
     IF(AND(K98>10,K98<=50),
        MROUND(K98,5),
        MROUND(K98,10)))
)
```